# MySql partial search which starts in the middle of word

Tags: mysql, search

I've got this query.

```
SELECT user_id FROM wp_user_search  WHERE MATCH (user_data) AGAINST('$input < $input*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I want to find user called Daniel. When I insert dan, da,dani etc it works perfectly. But it does not work when I write something like: aniel, iel etc.

Is there any way doing search in this way?

Comment: Try with LIKE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_user_search WHERE user_data LIKE '%daniel%'
```

If you use the % wildcard at the begining and at the end, it will match 'daniel' anywhere in between the name. So it will match 'bladaniel', or 'bladanielbla', for instance.

Comment: How to deal with the situation when multiple words are used for searching?